# Creating a SPA using AngularJS how can show a template only to authenticated users?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I'm creating a SPA using AngularJS and Bootstrap. Let's say my web application serves authenticated and unauthenticated users.The unauthenticated user sees a brochure site with a top menu nav. with about us, contact, etc. links. I define my routes and content i.e. partials are swapped in and out of the main body and everything works fine.

He then logs in and is authenticated. Now I want him to see a left hand nav. menu and content on the right. Only the content on the right is swapped in and out. So there's two page templates (1) the brochure site template - menu on top and (2) the secure site template - menu on side + top.

What's the most efficient way to do this with Angular? Do I load the same side menu with every partial using the ng-include directive? e.g. ng-include src='menu.html'?

It would be nice if there was some way to specify two 'master' page templates !

Answer (score 4):

You can do some pretty nifty stuff with a combination of CSS and `ngSwitch`, depending on your needs. Here's a simple example:

```html
<body ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div ng-switch="currentUser.loggedIn">
    <div ng-switch-when="false">
      <div class='top'>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <a href='about'>About</a>
        <a href='contact'>Contact</a>
        <a ng-click='login()'>Login</a>
      </div>
      <div ng-view>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="true">
      <div class='side'>
        <h2>Authenticated</h2>
        <a href='about'>About</a>
        <a href='contact'>Contact</a>
        <a ng-click='logout()'>Logout</a>
      </div>
      <div ng-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now you can switch between the two layouts by changing the `currentUser.loggedIn` value (which is what `login()` and `logout()` do). Here's an example based on this concept: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ng1KGe0Qt9Lpdl2jfhNX?p=preview (click the links to see the effects).

It's also possible that, depending on your server-side technology and stack (including templates and CSS), it may be just as easy to serve up one of two different Angular HTML pages based on whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Hi Brandon, this looks good but if I refresh the page I loose the currentUser.loggedIn state. Is there any way to persist for the duration of the user session ?

Comment: My implementation of `currentUser` was basically fake; a mock of an actual service that would probably be backed by some server-side session support of some kind (at least in order to be secure). If you don't care about security, you could persist it to a cookie, or localStorage, or something like that.

Comment: I've used the $resource service to get information about the current user from a `/getcurrentuser` URI, for instance. Then use that service throughout the app in controllers where you need them.